# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите. когда пишу вот такой код

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
p = (a + b + c)/2
S = p(p - a)(p - b)(p - c)
math.sqrt(S)
print(S)
```

выдает ошибку TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
это наверняка что-то простое, но я никак не могу в чем же дело. Заранее благодарю

Comment: на бумаге, конечно, знаки умножения можно пропускать...

Comment: `p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)`

Comment: Я так подозреваю, результат извлечения квадратного корня надо куда-то сохранять (например, в ту же `S`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка в `S = p(p - a)(p - b)(p - c)`

`p` содержит вещественное значение (`float`)

А `p(p - a)` синтаксис вызова объекта как функции.

Думаю, правильный код будет такой:

```
S = p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)
```

Comment: действительно, как можно было пропустить знаки умножения, бооожеее:(
спасибо!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 2):

- `p(...)` - вызов объекта p как функции с аргументом из скобок
- `p*(...)` - умножение p на результат выражения в скобках.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
p = (a + b + c)/2
S = (p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)) ** 0.5
# необходимо поставить знаки умножения
# корень можно вычислить как число в степени 1/2 т.е. ** 0.5
print(S)
```

Comment: В чем смысл ответа? Ваш ответ ничем не отличается от ответа @gil9red.

Comment: `корень можно вычислить как число в степени 1/2 т.е. ** 0.5` - нет разницы, использовать math.sqrt или возведение в степень 0.5